# How to let the AlarmManager not execute my notification if the trigger time I set is in the past?

Tags: android, alarmmanager

It say in this [section](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms#set) of Android dev doc on Scheduling Repeating Alarms that "if trigger time you specify is in the past, the alarm triggers immediately". So if right now is 9am, and I set the AlarmManager to execute my daily notification at 8am, it won't wait until tomorrow at 8am to execute the notification, it will immediately pop up. How do I make it not pop up?

Here is my commented code:

```
/**
* Show alertDialog to pick time
* @param v
*/
@Override
public void onClick(View v){
   Calendar c=Calendar.getInstance();
   mHour=c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
   mMinute=c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
   TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog=new TimePickerDialog(this,
        new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int hour, int 
              minute) {
                timeSet.setText(hour+":"+minute);
                //storing the inputted hour and time, so they reappear when 
                //app reopens
                editor.putInt("Hour",hour);
                editor.putInt("Minute",minute);
                editor.apply();

                scheduleNotification(hour,minute);
            }
        },mHour,mMinute,true);
   timePickerDialog.show();
}

/**
*Building Intent for AlarmReceiver and PendingIntent.
* Give PendingIntent to AlarmManager
* @param hour user-inputted hour of day
* @param minute user-inputted minute of day
*/
public void scheduleNotification(int hour, int minute){
 Intent intent1=new Intent(this,AlarmReceiver.class);
 //FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT: if the described PendingIntent already exists,
 //keep it but replace its extra data with what is in this new Intent.
 PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this
        ,0
        ,intent1
        ,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
 AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)this.getSystemService(this.ALARM_SERVICE);
 Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();

 calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,hour);
 calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,minute);
 //RTC_WAKEUP: wake up the device when it goes off.
 am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP
        , calendar.getTimeInMillis()
        ,AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY
        ,pendingIntent);
  }
```

AlarmReceiver.class is for making the notification when it Receives the phone receives the pendingIntent and use it to call AlarmReceiver.class (to make notification).

Answer (score 0):

You can add a check code with your specific time and current time:

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,hour);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,minute);

    long _alarm = 0;
    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
    if(calendar.getTimeInMillis() <= now.getTimeInMillis())
        _alarm = calendar.getTimeInMillis() + (AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY+1);
    else
        _alarm = calendar.getTimeInMillis();

    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP
    , _alarm 
    ,AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY
    ,pendingIntent);
```

Comment: What is alarm? If set time is behind the present time, why do you need INTERVAL_DAY+1? That is 2 days from set time. I think 1 day is enough.